# Issue getting index on click of paginated results in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, pagination, server-side

I am having some issues, In my app i have some paginated results but when I add the variable let i = index in ngFor, i can get the results for the first 10 items only not the paginated items? So If i go to page 2 and click on teh first item the index is 1 again as I have done index + 1.

So far code is:

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  collection: any;
  p: number;
  itemsPerPage = 10;
  totalItems: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllData();
  }

    getIndex(i) {
    console.log(i + 1);
  }

  getAllData() {
    const url = `https://xxxx/api/houses?page=1&pageSize=${this.itemsPerPage}`;
    this.http.get(url).subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.collection = data;
      this.totalItems = 450;
    });
  }

  getPage(page) {
    const url = `https://xxxx/api/houses?page=${page}&pageSize=${this.itemsPerPage}`;
    this.http.get(url).subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.collection = data;
      this.totalItems = 450;
    });
  }
}
```

component.html

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage , currentPage: p, totalItems: totalItems }  let i = index"> {{item.name}}                     <button (click)='getIndex(i)'>Index</button>
    </li>
</ul>

    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="getPage(p = $event)"></pagination-controls>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is supposed to happen? What do you want to do?

Comment: So when I click on the Index button clickIndex, its supposed to give me the index of the item, but at the moment if you look at the stackblitz, it only gives me the index of the first page items, if I go to page 2 and click on item 1 it still gives me number 1 when it should be 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the `getIndex` method like this to calculate the total index with taking the pagination into account:

```js
  getIndex(i) {
    let pageCoefficient;
    if (!this.p || this.p === 1) {
      pageCoefficient = 0;
    } else {
      pageCoefficient = (this.p - 1) * this.itemsPerPage;
    }
    console.log(i + 1 + pageCoefficient);
    return i + 1 + pageCoefficient;
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-joshko?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: OK great, but originally I was using the index value to pass the value to a router link `[routerLink]="['/details', i + 1]"` How could I achieve this?

Comment: Pass the `getIndex` value? `[routerLink]="['/details', getIndex(i)]"`. What's the problem with that?

Comment: Comes back as undefined

Comment: You're returning the value, right? I'll update my answer

Comment: I've updated the stackblitz as well; you can see the each number in the button now.